# Discord clicking button using api and requests in python not working

Tags: python, button, python-requests, discord, interaction

I have made this code to make a user interact with a button of my bot’s message, but i am unable to make it work. Please help.I get the following error:

{"code": 50035, "errors": {"session_id": {"_errors": [{"code": "BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED", "message": "This field is required"}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body”}

```
header = {
  'authorization': auth
}

r = requests.get("https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/<channel_id>/messages", headers = header)

message = json.loads(r.text)[0]

data = {
        "type": 3,
        "guild_id": '<guild_id>',
        "channel_id": '<channel_id>',
        "message_id": message['id'],
        "application_id": '<bot_id>', #the id of the bot to which i want to interact
        "data": {
                "component_type": 2,
                "custom_id": message['components'][0]['components'][2]['custom_id'] #gets the custom_id of the button to interact
        }
}

r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions', json = data, headers = header)
```

Comment: you have  to use `print( r.text )` to see if there is error message from server

Comment: yeah, just realised, thanks for the info! 
I get the error:
{"code": 50035, "errors": {"session_id": {"_errors": [{"code": "BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED", "message": "This field is required"}]}}, "message": "Invalid Form Body"}

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, I need to add a session_id under the data dict, the problem got solved! Thanks furas for your help!

The code now:

```
data = {
        "type": 3,
        "guild_id": '<guild_id>',
        "channel_id": '<channel_id>',
        "message_id": message['id'],
        "session_id": '<session_id>', #if you don't know the string, a random string worked for me
        "application_id": '<bot_id>', #the id of the bot to which i want to interact
        "data": {
                "component_type": 2,
                "custom_id": message['components'][0]['components'][2]['custom_id'] #gets the custom_id of the button to interact
        }
}
```